# What is the Java equivalent to php json_encode

Tags: java, php, json

I am implementing an api call in Java, the only example provided is in PHP, my question what is the java equivalent of json_encode so we get exactly the same output.

```
    foreach($products_from_order as $item_id => $item)
    {
        $value[] = array(
            'product_sku'    =>$item['sku'],
            'product_name'   =>$item['name'],
            'product_desc'   =>$item['description'],
            'product_price'  =>$item['price'],
            'product_url'    =>$item['url'],
            'product_image'  => $item['image'],
        );
    }

    $apiData = array("merchant_id"       => $merchantId,
        "order_id"          => $orderId,
        "customer_name"     => $customerName,
        "customer_email"    => $customerEmail,
        "purchase_date"     => $purchaseDate,
        "products"          => $value,
        "key"               => $apiKey,
        "hmac"              => $calculatedHmac
    );
    $data_string = json_encode($apiData)
```

I now have an example output so I suppose I just need to know the easiest way to do this in java

```
{
   "merchant_id":"526",
   "order_id":"15",
   "customer_name":"Tom Tester",
   "customer_email":"larry+tomtester@acompany.com",
   "purchase_date":"2017-01-27 22:05:56",
   "key":"24e694753d1c6d957882d4d560902b3f05454a0357b4c73a5bc66469653644cf9374ed5de8a2781d4151732299e821c4adf726f884923a46ae60a43d1b197164",
   "hmac":"kH9BBiRPMdHTP\\/dZgcUCPaldhpL9ttUw+lYl7LdB32Q=",
   "products":[
      {
         "product_sku":"47",
         "product_name":"HP LP3065",
         "product_desc":"\\r\\n\\tStop your co-workers in their tracks with the stunning new 30-inch diagonal HP LP3065 Flat Panel Monitor. This flagship monitor features best-in-class performance and presentation features on a huge wide-aspect screen while letting you work as comfortably as possible - you might even forget you&#39;re at the office\\r\\n..",
         "product_price":"100.0000",
         "product_url":"http:\\/\\/ts.oc-develop.com\\/index.php?route=product\\/product&amp;product_id=47",
         "product_image":"http:\\/\\/ts.oc-develop.com\\/image\\/cache\\/catalog\\/demo\\/hp_1-500x500.jpg"
      },
      {
         "product_sku":"41",
         "product_name":"iMac",
         "product_desc":"\\r\\n\\tJust when you thought iMac had everything, now there\\u00b4s even more. More powerful Intel Core 2 Duo processors. And more memory standard. Combine this with Mac OS X Leopard and iLife \\u00b408, and it\\u00b4s more all-in-one than ever. iMac packs amazing performance into a stunningly slim space.\\r\\n..",
         "product_price":"100.0000",
         "product_url":"http:\\/\\/ts.oc-develop.com\\/index.php?route=product\\/product&amp;product_id=41",
         "product_image":"http:\\/\\/ts.oc-develop.com\\/image\\/cache\\/catalog\\/demo\\/imac_1-500x500.jpg"
      },
      {
         "product_sku":"28",
         "product_name":"HTC Touch HD",
         "product_desc":"\\r\\n\\tHTC Touch - in High Definition. Watch music videos and streaming content in awe-inspiring high definition clarity for a mobile experience you never thought possible. Seductively sleek, the HTC Touch HD provides the next generation of mobile functionality, all at a simple touch. Fully integrated with Windows Mobile Professional 6.1, ultrafast 3.5G, GPS, 5MP camera, plus lots more - all delivered on a breathtakingly crisp 3.8&quot; WVGA touchscreen - you can take control of your mobile world wi..",
         "product_price":"100.0000",
         "product_url":"http:\\/\\/ts.oc-develop.com\\/index.php?route=product\\/product&amp;product_id=28",
         "product_image":"http:\\/\\/ts.oc-develop.com\\/image\\/cache\\/catalog\\/demo\\/htc_touch_hd_1-500x500.jpg"
      }
   ]
}
```

**Update**
So I went with the Gson library

Create a POJO for Order and Person

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Order
{
    private String merchantId;
    private String customerEmail;
    private String customerName;
    private String orderId;
    private String purchaseDate;
    private String key;
    private String hmac;
    private List<Product> products = new ArrayList();

    public String getCustomerEmail()
    {
        return customerEmail;
    }

    public void setCustomerEmail(String customerEmail)
    {
        this.customerEmail = customerEmail;
    }

    public String getCustomerName()
    {
        return customerName;
    }

    public void setCustomerName(String customerName)
    {
        this.customerName = customerName;
    }

    public String getOrderId()
    {
        return orderId;
    }

    public void setOrderId(String orderId)
    {
        this.orderId = orderId;
    }

    public String getPurchaseDate()
    {
        return purchaseDate;
    }

    public void setPurchaseDate(String purchaseDate)
    {
        this.purchaseDate = purchaseDate;
    }

    public String getMerchantId()
    {
        return merchantId;
    }

    public void setMerchantId(String merchantId)
    {
        this.merchantId = merchantId;
    }

    public String getKey()
    {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key)
    {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getHmac()
    {
        return hmac;
    }

    public void setHmac(String hmac)
    {
        this.hmac = hmac;
    }

    public List<Product> getProducts()
    {
        return products;
    }

    public void addProducts(Product product)
    {
        products.add(product);
    }
}


public class Product
{
    private String productSku;
    private String productName;
    private String productDescription;
    private String productPrice;
    private String productUrl;
    private String productImage;

    public String getProductSku()
    {
        return productSku;
    }

    public void setProductSku(String productSku)
    {
        this.productSku = productSku;
    }

    public String getProductName()
    {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName)
    {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public String getProductDescription()
    {
        return productDescription;
    }

    public void setProductDescription(String productDescription)
    {
        this.productDescription = productDescription;
    }

    public String getProductPrice()
    {
        return productPrice;
    }

    public void setProductPrice(String productPrice)
    {
        this.productPrice = productPrice;
    }

    public String getProductUrl()
    {
        return productUrl;
    }

    public void setProductUrl(String productUrl)
    {
        this.productUrl = productUrl;
    }

    public String getProductImage()
    {
        return productImage;
    }

    public void setProductImage(String productImage)
    {
        this.productImage = productImage;
    }
}
```

and then called it as follows:

```
Order order = new Order();
        order.setMerchantId(String.valueOf(526));
        order.setOrderId(String.valueOf(15));
        order.setCustomerName("Tom Tester");
        order.setCustomerEmail("larry+tomtester@trustspot.io");
        order.setPurchaseDate("2017-01-27 22:05:56");
        order.setHmac("kH9AAiRPMdHTP/dZgcUCPaldhpL9ttUw+lYl7LdB32Q=");

        Product p1 = new Product();
        p1.setProductSku(String.valueOf(47));
        p1.setProductName("HP LP3065");
        p1.setProductDescription("\r\nStop your co-workers in their tracks with the stunning new 30-inc");
        p1.setProductPrice("100.0000");
        p1.setProductUrl("http://ts.oc-develop.com/index.php?route=product/product&amp;product_id=47");
        p1.setProductImage("http://ts.oc-develop.com/image/cache/catalog/demo/hp_1-500x500.jpg");
        order.addProducts(p1);
        Product p2 = new Product();
        p2.setProductSku(String.valueOf(41));
        p2.setProductName("iMac");
        p2.setProductDescription("\r\nJust when you thought iMac had everything,");
        p2.setProductPrice("100.0000");
        p2.setProductUrl("http://ts.oc-develop.com/index.php?route=product/product&amp;product_id=41");
        p2.setProductImage("http://ts.oc-develop.com/image/cache/catalog/demo/imac_1-500x500.jpg");
        order.addProducts(p2);

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES).setPrettyPrinting().create();
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(order));
```

Gave the output

```
{
  "merchant_id": "526",
  "customer_email": "larry+tomtester@trustspot.io",
  "customer_name": "Tom Tester",
  "order_id": "15",
  "purchase_date": "2017-01-27 22:05:56",
  "hmac": "kH9AAiRPMdHTP/dZgcUCPaldhpL9ttUw+lYl7LdB32Q\u003d",
  "products": [
    {
      "product_sku": "47",
      "product_name": "HP LP3065",
      "product_description": "\r\nStop your co-workers in their tracks with the stunning new 30-inc",
      "product_price": "100.0000",
      "product_url": "http://ts.oc-develop.com/index.php?route\u003dproduct/product\u0026amp;product_id\u003d47",
      "product_image": "http://ts.oc-develop.com/image/cache/catalog/demo/hp_1-500x500.jpg"
    },
    {
      "product_sku": "41",
      "product_name": "iMac",
      "product_description": "\r\nJust when you thought iMac had everything,",
      "product_price": "100.0000",
      "product_url": "http://ts.oc-develop.com/index.php?route\u003dproduct/product\u0026amp;product_id\u003d41",
      "product_image": "http://ts.oc-develop.com/image/cache/catalog/demo/imac_1-500x500.jpg"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now just wondering why they have escaped '/' such as in hmac, there is no mention if doing this in the api document, but it is clearly there in the example json, is this done by json_encode or something else, it doesn't seem necessary to me.

The escapes were just caused by them copying and pasting their log output. Since this question has got rather specific Im going to delete it doesnt seem that useful to anyone else

Comment: Googling "java json encode" didn't get you anything useful?

Comment: @ceejayoz but the output has to be identical so I was looking for someone with actual experience of this, I have just been strugglig with a simailr issue with base64 , Java wasnt returning the same value as the php base64_encode function

Comment: Then show us an example of the Java code you've written, the expected JSON result from PHP, and the Java JSON result that's not correct. It's entirely possible for both to produce JSON *if you're doing it right*.

Comment: @ceejayoz Until 10 seconds ago I didnt know the expected result from PHP I just knew they created the data using json_encode hence the reason for the question !

Comment: It's JSON. It doesn't care what tech output it.

Comment: @ceejayoz but I didnt have the json output I only had example php input so I didnt know what the output was meant to look like, but I think this is really a java question not a php one so I dont think you are any help to me here with your comments.

Comment: My comments are me trying to understand your question. It came as a surprise to me that you somehow had the PHP source code but not the resulting output. Creating that JSON output shouldn't give a Java JSON library any difficulty.

Comment: @ceejayoz I had the source code but not the output because this was the only documentation the company Im trying to integrate with provided me, i.e example code for php client. Yes now that I have the json output  I shoud be able to sort this out.

Comment: @ceejayoz So I have it creating equivalent json using gson except my json doesnt escape '/'s, i.e the actual value for hmac is kH9BBiRPMdHTP/dZgcUCPaldhpL9ttUw+lYl7LdB32Q= but in the json they have it as kH9BBiRPMdHTP\\/dZgcUCPaldhpL9ttUw+lYl7LdB32Q=, is this a function of json encode or something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no equivalent in Java, but you could try using some 3rd party libraries like GSON or org.json.*

Answer (score 0):

If the result object stays as "flat" as in your example, you could consider constructing the object yourself, which I also did on several occasions to avoid external libraries. Just loop through the array and fill the fields in e.g. a String.

Comment: Ive just realized its notflat as $value is also an array, Ill'update the question

Comment: @GerardBlinkhorst sorry I think I clicked on that accidently